# Talend custom function

Tags: talend

How i can apply custom function with tmap, or may be with tsystem. I want to decrypt crypted columns on-the-fly  with my custom function. I can write all encrypted values to file, then write from file to tsystem, or tmap, and decrypt values. What is the best way for this?

Comment: You should be able to access your custom public functions as long as you load the jar into the project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Java routines. you can create java methods and call anywhere. for example

```
public static String decrypt(String encryptStr){
                    String decrypted = null;
        try {

            while(encryptStr != null){
                try
                {

                    String key = "Bar12345Bar12345"; // 128 bit key
                    // Create key and cipher
                    Key aesKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
                    // encrypt the text
                    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesKey);

                    // for decryption
                    byte[] bb = new byte[encryptStr.length()];
                    for (int i=0; i<encryptStr.length(); i++) {
                        bb[i] = (byte) encryptStr.charAt(i);
                    }

                    // decrypt the text
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aesKey);
                    decrypted = new String(cipher.doFinal(bb));

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Snake_H.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return decrypted;
    }
```

For encrypts follow the same kind of methods. you can call this java method at anywhere like **tmap** 
Reference [Talend Routines](https://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-code-routines-reference.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you are speaking about routines, simply call the desired method everywhere you can put some java code.
For example, as an expression for the output flow, you can have something like:
`yourClass.yourMethod(...)`

Hope this helps.